# pthread use condition variable to start a few threads "at once"

Tags: pthreads, posix, condition-variable

i've just started playing around with posix pthreads (on c++).
I'm trying to use a conditional variable to start many threads at once.

Does someone know a better way to do this or can give an example of how one would?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ruled out [pthread_cond_broadcast](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_cond_broadcast.html), and are trying to do this you probably have already created the threads and might be looking for a way to gather release them all at once.  If that is the case you may want to use a barrier.

You can initialize a barrier with [pthread_barrier_init](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/pthread_barrier_init.html) which takes a parameter for the number of threads you want to wait on.  When the specified number of threads have hit a [pthread_barrier_wait](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/pthread_barrier_wait.html) statement all the waiting threads are released at once (i.e. marked ready to run), though of course they remain subject to the whims of scheduler as to which may or may not immediately get processor time.

A very simple sketch

```
void* tfunc(void *)
{
    pthread_barrier_wait(&bar);

    //do stuff
}

pthread_barrier_init(&bar, NULL, 4);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, tfunc, NULL);
```

When the 4th thread hits the `wait` all the waiting threads will continue.